# Integrated Crashlytics Kit failed with Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics

First of all, using Eclipse. It creates 4 projects(as libraries) after plugin installed and creates kit-libs with those 4 projects in my android-project. Then I built the project and the apk compiled successfully but ran failed. Failed log:

```
12-22 17:50:07.377: E/dalvikvm(8452): Could not find class 'io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit[]', referenced from method com.pplive.test.fabric.MainActivity.onCreate
12-22 17:50:07.377: W/dalvikvm(8452): VFY: unable to resolve new-array 650 ([Lio/fabric/sdk/android/Kit;) in Lcom/pplive/test/fabric/MainActivity;
12-22 17:50:07.377: D/dalvikvm(8452): VFY: replacing opcode 0x23 at 0x0004
12-22 17:50:07.377: D/dalvikvm(8452): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0ff0 at 0x09 in Lcom/pplive/test/fabric/MainActivity;.onCreate
12-22 17:50:07.383: D/AndroidRuntime(8452): Shutting down VM
12-22 17:50:07.383: W/dalvikvm(8452): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41be8930)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit[]
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at com.pplive.test.fabric.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.internal.InstrumentationDelegate.callActivityOnCreate(InstrumentationDelegate.java:76)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1235)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:812)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:579)
12-22 17:50:07.386: E/AndroidRuntime(8452):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Do I need to modify the build path in property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found same issue couple of days ago, Yesterday I have resolved this issue by:

1. By compile my project using 1.7. As crashlytics compiled in 1.7
2. Installing build-tool 20 from sdk manager.

Hopes it worked for you too.

Comment: Thanks, it works!!! According to your tips, I replace the jdk and change my eclipse to luna eclipse, instead of adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130717 which I used before.

Comment: the above u mentioned. Btw i have solved the problem by deleting all fabric stuff and adding again!